# Can't add the extension method to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, silverlight, generics

Okay, so I was trying to add the ForEach extension method to the linq, since there is no ForEach for IEnumerables but for some reason, I can't see it.

The extension method is :

```
public  static  IEnumerable<TSource> ForEach<TSource>(Func<TSource> action)
{ 
    yield return action();
}
```

And when I try to call it(`gdMain` is a `Grid`):

[image]

Comment: This isn't an extension method.

Comment: To begin with, don't you think that an *extension* method would need a `this` first argument? Why don't you just look up any extension method on MSDN to see what their signatures are? And finally... `Enumerable.ForEach`. Sigh.

Comment: yeah, i forgot about that, but even after adding this, it doesn't work..
http://i.imgur.com/M94OpQJ.png

Comment: Since you updated your code, please update the code in the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have intellisense showing something as you try in your code, you have to add an argument. `this IEnumerable<TSource> source`.

Or it won't be an extension method for an `IEnumerable<TSource>` (and `gdMain.Children.Cast<UIElement>()` will return an `IEnumerable<UIElement>`)

```
public  static  IEnumerable<TSource> ForEach<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource> action)
{ 
    yield return action();   
}
```